# Change the entire product string in WooCommerce Subscripitons

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I want to change the text and the order of my price string in WooCommerce Subscriptions. Right now it says:

*“$35.00 on the 1st of each month for 11 months and a $35.00 sign-up fee.”*

and I want it to say:

**“$35.00 for the first box and then $35.00 on the 1st of each month for 11 months.”**

I found this code that I can use to change "sign-up fee" to "for the first box":

```
 /* WooCommerce Subscriptions Price String */

 function wc_subscriptions_custom_price_string( $pricestring ) {
    $newprice = str_replace( 'sign-up fee', 'for the first box', $pricestring );
    return $newprice;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_subscriptions_product_price_string', 'wc_subscriptions_custom_price_string' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_subscription_price_string', 'wc_subscriptions_custom_price_string' );
```

Now it says *“$35.00 on the 1st of each month for 11 months and a $35.00 for the first box.”*

**How can I change the order?**

Comment: Are all your subscriptions the same price?

Comment: Right now there is only one subscription but there may be more in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply reorder the string by exploding the original into an array:

```
function wc_subscriptions_custom_price_string( $pricestring ) {
   $replace_price = str_replace( 'sign-up fee', 'for the first box', $pricestring );
   $aPrice = explode(" and a ", $replace_price);
   $newprice = $aPrice[1] . " and then " . $aPrice[0]; 
   $finalprice = str_replace(" on "," +shipping on ", $newprice);
   return finalprice;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_subscriptions_product_price_string', 'wc_subscriptions_custom_price_string' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_subscription_price_string', 'wc_subscriptions_custom_price_string' );
```

See: [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Or if you want to get fancy:

```
$newprice = implode(" and then ", array_reverse($aPrice));
```

Comment: Ok this worked great but I had a slight change after speaking with the client. They would like it to say "$35.00 for the first box and then $35.00 +shipping on the 1st of each month for 11 months.

Comment: How can we add '+ shipping' between the price and the "on the 1st of each..."?